# Block specific websites in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, blocking, windows-firewall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blocking web sites with Windows Firewall](https://superuser.com/questions/270524/blocking-web-sites-with-windows-firewall)

I want to block specific websites from being accessed from my computer without using any other software.
Is it possible to do with windows firewall?

should have been more specific... my roommate uses my laptop to view pornos. I did try blocking sites using avast antivirus....but he turn it off....so no blocking. thats why i want it to be done at system level...where he can not find and shut it off.

Comment: You could do this with the hosts file

Comment: I think you can block IP address ranges using Windows Firewall, not URLs, so you can ping the website you want to block in the command prompt to get the IP address and set up a new block rule in  Windows Firewall. You can also use the hosts file, as Dave mentioned - [**See this question**](http://superuser.com/q/497023/138020).

Comment: @amiregelz - This could be a dangerous thing to do, 1 IP can relate to many websites (shared hosting for example)

Comment: @DaveRook Right, I wouldn't do that. Much better to use the hosts file as you just need to type the website's URL there.

Comment: IMO, this is not what the firewall is intended for.

Comment: should have been more specific...
my roommate uses my laptop to view pornos. I did try blocking sites using avast antivirus....but he turn it off....so no blocking.
thats why i want it to be done at system level...where he can not find and shut it off.

Comment: @ankit your roommate - did you gave him admin access to your laptop or is he using regular user account? Maybe you could implement some parental control settings for your computer? There are many software out there that will allow to implement desired level of restrictions. Take a look in here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/parental-controls

Comment: @ankit @DaveRook Blocking by URL is not really working for determined fellow - he can always bypass limitation via online proxy services with URL encode/encryption as in the `hidemyass.com`. Parental controls work more heuristically and are not based on simple URL/domain comparison.

Comment: @ankit Additionally if you prefer to use firewall - use something like  COMODO firewall - its free, gives you ability to block by URL and most importantly - it allows you to protect the settings with password, therefore it wont allow your roommate to change settings.

Answer (score 0):

if you block IP Adresses, you will block other Webpages hosted on the same IP too.

Here is a Tutorial to edit your hostfile:

http://techfleece.com/2011/08/15/how-to-edit-your-hosts-file-in-windows-7/

Please remember running notepad as administrator.

For blocking a website write an Entry like this:

127.0.0.1 blocked.tld

Alternative

You can try to configure your Router using the Open DNS Servers and use it with an account. So you can block all porn related requests. But the Setup is a little bit tricky. You have to enter the opendns DNS Servers and you have to link your external IP Address to your Account. They offer a tool for this.

If you use the hosts File Setup, make sure that the user your roommate uses don't have Administrator Permissions. Then he can't change it. Unfortunately you have to enter every porn site by your own.

If you have the skills to, i would prefer the opendns Setup.

More informations can be found here:

http://www.opendns.com/

Answer (score 0):

Despite this appearing as if it is done via IE, it (apparently) does it in the firewall.

> Access Internet Explorer from your computer.
>
> Choose "Tools" at the top of the screen. Select "Internet Options"
>   from the drop-down menu.
>
> Click the "Content" tab in the Internet Options menu. Scroll down to
>   the second menu option, "Content Advisor," and click. Wait for the new
>   menu to appear.
>
> Click "Settings" within the Content Advisor menu. When the "Supervisor
>   Password Required" dialog box appears, enter your Windows 7 password
>   into this field and press "Enter."
>
> Click the "Approved Sites" tab at the top of the screen. Wait for the
>   words "Allow This Website," along with an empty dialog, box to appear.
>
> Enter the full URL of the site you wish to block access to in the
>   empty dialog box under "Allow This Website." Check "Never." ("Always"
>   is the other option.)
>
> Click "Apply" to confirm that you are blocking access to the chosen
>   website. Click "OK" when you get a message confirming the change has
>   gone into effect. The website is now blocked by your Windows 7
>   firewall.

[Source](http://techtips.salon.com/block-access-website-using-microsoft-windows-firewall-1411.html)

I would also recommend updating the hosts file instead since you can copy and paste hosts files between machines (in some situations). See C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc